# Android Studio on Mac: command for uncomment/comment lines of code overriden

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I updated my Android Studio recently (Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1) and whenever I press:

**Command (⌘) + 7** it opens "Structure" window instead of uncommenting/commenting lines of code.

How can I get rid off this keybind for opening "Structure"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: Open preferences -> keymap -> search for "structure" and remove the key binding, or add new shortcut cmd for comment line of code.